# android - jackson get null fields value as empty string

Tags: android, jackson

My JSON stream can be different each time. For example sometime it can include a "Song" field and sometime not.

I am getting this fields value asText ? How to tell Jackson to get this value as an Empty String if it is not defined ?

Example

```
"Content": "MusicContent",
"Song": "Track_1",
```

if try node.get("Song").asText() it will give "Track_1"

```
"Content": "MusicContent",
```

Now , if i try to get node.get("Song") it gives null pointer exception. I want to get an empty string when calling asText().

How can i do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could check for null before calling the asText() on the node. i would probably do it like this :

```
if (node.get("Song") != null){
  myString = node.get("Song").asText();
} else {
  myString = "";
}
```

Or in a fancy way like this :

```
myString = ((node.get("Song")!=null) ? node.get("Song").asText() : "");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Instead of checking this for each node , i thought maybe Jackson has a mapping feature for this.

Comment: Well, if you intent to build a POJO for it, it's not a big deal anymore. Just a ```getContent()``` method which checks ```mContent``` to return an empty string.